# Finding square roots of $7 - 24i$

Tags: complex-numbers

How do I find all complex numbers $z$ such that :

$$z^2=7−24i$$

I don't even know where to begin please help. The $z^2$ throws me off.

Comment: If you don't know where to begin on a complex number problem, try $z=a+bi$ and see if it helps.  It doesn't always help, but now you have a path forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See that $z=a+bi$.  Thus, $z^2=a^2-b^2+2abi$.  Setting it equal, we get

$$a^2-b^2=7\\2ab=-24$$

$$a=-12/b$$

$$(-12/b)^2-b^2=7$$

$$b^4+7b^2-144=0$$

$$b=3$$

$$a=-12/3=-4$$

Thus,

$$z=-4+3i$$

Similarly, $-z$ is another solution, giving us our two desired solutions:

> $$z=\pm(4-3i)$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: substitute $z=x+iy$, equal the real and imaginary parts, derive $z=\pm(4-3i)$.

Comment: Aw darn, my silly mistakes let you beat me to the good answer.  Rats!

Comment: @SimpleArt Couldn't just stand by watching everybody go polar here ;-)

Answer (score 1):

$(1)$ Write $7 -24i$ in trigonometric form. (This looks like $r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$) and is shortened to $r cis \theta$.)

$(2)$ Set up the formula for the two square roots in trigonometric form. They have the form

$$w_k = \sqrt {r}\times cis (\frac{\theta + 360°k}{2})$$ for $k = 1$ and $k = 2$  (assuming degrees for the angles)

$(3)$ Plug in $k = 1$ and $k = 2$ into this formula and simplify the angle(s).

$(4)$ Evaluate and rewrite in standard form $(a + bi)$ if that is required.